# Bargain Finder Max v5 - REST API - how to get the flights date time from the response?

Tags: sabre

I am using Sabre api https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/versions/v500/reference-documentation#/default/CreateBargainFinderMax

scheduleDescs only contains the flight time, how i can tell the flight date? if for example there are connection flights that scheduled  a different date from the first flight?

[gist](https://gist.github.com/tomer-yechiel/17564db392841c6f85220f8c0bd3a3f3) with example of response